# Bounding an integral in Stein-Shakarchi Real Analysis Chapter 4 Exercise 28 part (a)

Tags: real-analysis

Stein-Shakarchi's Real Analysis, Chapter 4, Exercise 28, Part (a) asks

> Suppose $H = L^ 2(B)$, where $B$ is the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $K(x, y)$ be a measurable function on $B\times B$ that satisfies $|K(x, y)|\leq A|x-y|^{-d+\alpha}$ for some $\alpha>0$ whenever $x, y\in B$. $\forall f \in H, x\in B$, define  $$(Tf)(x) = \int_B K(x, y)f(y)dy.$$ Prove that T is a bounded operator on $H$.

$\forall x \in B$, do a change of variables by shifting the origin,
$$\int_B |x-y|^{-d+\alpha}dy = \int_{B+x} |y|^{-d+\alpha}dy$$
then integrate in spherical coordinates,
$$< \int_{2B} |y|^{-d+\alpha}dy = \int_0^2 r^{-d+\alpha} Cr^{d-1}dr = C2^\alpha/\alpha$$
where $Cr^{d-1}$ is the surface area of a $d$-dimensional ball with radius $r$.

But I don't know how to use it to bound $||Tf||^2$.
$$|Tf(x)| = |\int_B K(x,y)f(y)dy| \leq A\int_B |x-y|^{-d+\alpha}|f(y)|dy$$
$$||Tf||^2 \leq A^2\int_B  \left(\int_B |x-y|^{-d+\alpha}|f(y)|dy\right)^2 dx$$

Doing Cauchy-Schwartz does not separate the integrand into parts that can be solved:

$$\left(\int_B |x-y|^{-d+\alpha}|f(y)|dy\right)^2 \leq 
\left(\int_B |x-y|^{-2d+2\alpha}dy\right)\left(\int_B |f(y)|^2dy\right)$$
The left integral would diverge if $\alpha \leq d/2$.

Trying to adjust the exponent does not help. Let $\beta > 0$, then
$$ \leq \left(\int_B |x-y|^{-d+\beta}dy\right)
\left(\int_B |x-y|^{-d + 2\alpha - \beta}|f(y)|^2dy\right)$$
Then the right integral cannot be evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $K\ge0$ and also  $f\ge0$, both to save typing and to ensure that all the integrals *exist* (in $[0,\infty]$). Of course this is wlog,  since in general $|Tf(x)|\le\int_B|K(x,y)f(y)|\,dy$.

The inequality you need holds for any $K$ such that $\int_BK(x,y)\,dy\le c$ and $\int_BK(x,y)\,dx\le c$.

**Main Trick:** Write $$K(x,y)f(y)=K(x,y)^{1/2}(K(x,y)^{1/2}f(y).$$

Applying Cauchy-Schwarz to that product shows that $$Tf(x)^2\le\int_BK(x,y)\,dy\int_BK(x,y)f(y)^2\,dy\le c\int_BK(x,y)f(y)^2\,dy.$$

Now apply Fubini, or rather Tonelli, to $\int_BTf(x)^2\,dx$.